# javascript - Redirect gives Unexpected token in JSON error

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to make a button redirect me to a php file with some parameters, so I made a javascript function to do it! But I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I made this script I made for the redirect:

```
window.onload = function{

var url=window.location.href;
var cliente="Prueba";

document.getElementById("textButton fbButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
        location.href ="[placeholder]/fb/login.php?url="+url+"&cliente="+cliente;
    });
}
```

And this is my button:

```
<button id="textButton fbButton" class="btnRedirectFB">Facebook login</button>
```

I have been trying to figure out what could be wrong, but I can't find the problem, could be something I don't see, or just me doing something dumb, I would like to know where I am failing! Thanks!

Comment: You can't have a space within an `id`

Comment: You also have not posted the json.

Comment: I am working on an already built web app, so that JSON could be messing with the redirect? the ID seems to be working, Kendo's button needs that textButton id to style it, so one is for kendo and the other for the function and it works just fine, the function had an alert for testing and it was being triggered. It won't work if I only use "fbButton" and "textButton" is being used with other button

Comment: The id with a space seems to actually work in Firefox, but the whole string is the id; in other words there's just one id value. Anyway the JSON is the important thing for the actual question. To see it you can use your browser's "Network" developer tab.

Comment: I used the Network developer tab and see no JSON at all

Comment: The error is happening in `jquery.validate.js`, it looks like you have something invalid in one of its configuration settings. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Oh boy, I'll look at it right away!